# In C, are you allowed to cast directly from a certain type of pointer to another?

Tags: c, pointers

Let's say you start with a void pointer, or a char pointer, or an int pointer, or whatever you would like to name.

```
    void *p = // initialized to something here
```

And we do a conversion like

```
    *((int *)((char *)p + 6)) = 5;
```

Does this mean we are basically casting a void pointer to a char pointer, doing some arithmetic, casting that to an int pointer, and then de-referencing it to store 5?

Or do we need to cast the char pointer back to a void pointer before it is safe to cast it to the int pointer?

*** Also, before casting from char* to int*, does there need to be a de-reference somewhere before the conversion?

Comment: I voted to close as "too localized" because practically speaking, a correct answer to this question seems unlikely to help even the OP to accomplish anything, let alone future readers.

Comment: @Karl I don't agree with you, pointer casts are rather confusing in C, and the OP needs clarification. The issue here is that casts between integer types such as between int and char is undefined behavior, while casting to void* isn't. So, it is a pretty good question. I'm getting quite tired of people closing everything for little or no reason, the community does not benefit from it in the slightest.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The conversion you have shown is syntactically valid C.  Casting through a `void *` type on the way to `int *` makes no difference.

Whether it is semantically correct depends on whether the memory pointed to by `(char *)p + 6` is correctly sized and aligned for access as `int`.

Comment: What do you mean that it's correctly sized&aligned for access as int?

Comment: @JacobHayden: There must be at least `sizeof(int)` bytes of memory at that location, and the address of the location must meet the alignment requirements for `int` (which are a property of the environment your code is running in).  You can guarantee correct alignment if the address is offset from another correctly aligned address by a multiple of `sizeof(int)` - correctly aligned addresses can be obtained by taking the address of an `int` object or from memory allocation functions like `malloc()`.

Answer (score 1):

Casting a char pointer back to a void pointer before casting it to an int pointer won't be any better than just casting a char pointer to an int pointer.  You've got to really know what you are doing to make it work though, because you have to deal with alignment issues.

Comment: On many platforms, values of certain types must be stored in memory a certain way.  For example, a 32-bit int typically has to be stored at an address that is evenly divisible by four.

Answer (score 1):

C is much more lenient than C++ in allowing potentially dangerous pointer typecasts. It stems from C's "the programmer knows what they're doing" philosophy. However, because of the potential dangers of typecasting, C++ introduces three types of casting, `static_cast`, `dynamic_cast`, and `reinterpret_cast`.

Recommended reading:

1. http://www.crasseux.com/books/ctutorial/Pointer-types.html
2. http://www.cplusplus.com/doc/tutorial/typecasting/

Answer (score 0):

Casting from a pointer to one integer type, to another pointer to a different integer type is undefined behavior if it leads to alignment issues (C99 6.3.2.3). If it doesn't, you can cast between them safely. `char` is an integer type.

(The C standard is a bit weird here, stating that this is UB. This should have been implementation-defined behavior, because it depends on the specific CPU architecture and is safe in many cases.)

In the case of your specific example, it does indeed mean what you describe. The reasons behind it are likely:

- You can't perform pointer arithmetics on a void pointer. Therefore it is typecasted to a char* so that the address could be altered to the original one + 6*sizeof(char), ie 6 bytes.
- Hopefully the programmer is aware of alignment and that it is safe to address whatever is at that specific address as an int. If so, it is perfectly safe to typecast to an int*.